# sql запрос в теле foreach для более 10к+ итераций

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

У меня есть csv документ со списком ссылок, которые есть в контенте постов сайта на WP. 
Эти ссылки нужно нужно удалить,оставив только их текст и поместив его в тэг span

Я начал с того, что все ссылки из csv файла поместил в массив.
Затем в цикле foreach я решил создать примерный sql запрос, просто для удаления всего атрибута href.
Но так как ссылок очень много, более 10к, все зависает. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно создать так много sql запросов в рамках цикла? Либо же эту задачу можно решить другим способом? Спасибо!

Comment: Положите этот CSV на  том хоста, где работает MySQL, в каталог secure_file_priv, и загрузите его одним запросом со всеми нужными  обработками.

Comment: Какая связь между твоим csv-файлом и ВП? И где надо удалять?

Comment: @SeVlad нужно найти и удалить ссылки в post_content 
я положил csv в корень темы, и в functions.php я добавил все ссылки которые мне нужно удалить в массив.

Comment: Где удалить? В файле или на сайте? Причём тут файл к ВП? Контента сайта находится в базе, а не в файлах.

Comment: @SeVlad
В этом csv файле список из кучи разных ссылок которые размещены в постах по всему сайту и которые нужно удалить. Я добавил все эти ссылки в массив и через цикл хочу пройтись по каждой ссылке и через sql запрос удалить ее из БД. Но так как ссылок очень много, у меня зависает все.

Comment: как у вас выглядит запрос на удаление ? каков план выполнения этого запроса (explain)

Comment: Код на скрине http://i.imgur.com/2n6qIjI.png

Comment: уууу ... как все запущено. ну тут ничего не сделаешь если таблица большая. разве что собирать по много ссылок за раз что бы получалось что то вроде `replace(replace(replace(post_content, $link[0], ''), $link[1], ''), $link[2], '')`. Если "ссылки" это что то вроде "http://..." то возможно будет более выгодной стратегией найти сначала посты содержащие хоть какие нибудь ссылки, сохранить их id в отдельной таблице и при обновлении использовать join что бы только в этих записях выполнялся update

Comment: Или даже загрузить все посты с ссылками в оперативку, произвести замены в ней и записать результат обратно в БД. Что бы не нагружать БД массой update. У вас же текущий вариант знаете что делает ? Поднимает всю таблицу с диска, пытается что нибудь заменить, пишет всю таблицу обратно на диск (при этом еще и в журнал) и так для каждой ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

10k запросов для базы данных - это ничто, выполняются за 1 секунду.

Если тормозит, то во-первых, заключи цикл с удалением в транзакцию. Это поможт обойти дефолтные настройки движка innodb которые замедляют запросы на изменение данных ради контроля их целостности.

Ну и разумеетcя надо убедиться что стоят индексы, на поля, которые используются в where.

Comment: А как транзакция поможет с зависанием?